# How can i restrict protect_from_forgery with exception rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, security

I have a rails application that is both a regular web page and an API.
I have activated the

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

in the ApplicationController and because of that I'm getting errors when doing POST request to the api (422 responses).

So I want to restrict the

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

to the regular and put

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

to my API(Wich is under the API/v1 namespace). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in respective controller, which is used for API calls.

The best way is to create a new `API::BaseController` controller:

```
class API::BaseController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

and extend all other API controllers from it. This way you don't need to repeat this declaration for every controller.